# With Delphi 11.2 and TeeChart converting VCL to FMX - Where is the function LoadChartFromfile?

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey, teechart

With TeeChart VCL there are two functions to save and load a chart:

- VclTee.TeeStore.SaveChartToFile
- VclTee.TeeStore.LoadChartFromFile

I do not find these functions in TeeChart FMX ?
I saw that a similar function exists in the unit FMXTee.Store but I do not have this unit in the distribution of Delphi 11.2

I tried to use the TeeChart.SaveToMetafile function but I have an error at execution and there is no function to load it.

TeeChart.SaveToMetafile function reports an error at execution.
Exception when rendering at canvas.

```
 Chart1.SaveToMetafile('c:\soft\teechart\chart.tee');
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you won't find equivalent functions for FMX TeeChart components that ship with Delphi. Why? Delphi ships with Standard edition of VCL TeeChart components and only Lite Edition of FMX TeeChart components.

So if you want same capabilities in FMX as you have now in VCL you will have to purchase at least Standard version of TeeChart components from Stema Software

To learn more about which features are included in each edition of TeeChart components check [Feature Matrix](https://www.steema.com/feature_matrix/vcl)

Comment: I confirm that the SaveChartTofile and LoadChartFromfile functions are available in the FMXTee.Store unit which is in the paid offer. 
I have tested the paid offer and it works. 
Thank you.